# Creating an integer parameter with values between 0 - 3 only

Tags: vb.net, enums, integer

I would like to use the parameter of an integer between number 0 - 3 only, how can I do that?

I've tried using enum, but it doesn't allow the starting number to be an integer like this

```
Public Enum Octet_Num As Integer
   0
   1
   2
   3
End Enum
```

The code below will work, but it seems that it doesn't practice a good coding standard?

```
Public Enum Octet_Num
   first_octet
   second_octet
   third_octet
   fourth_octet
End Enum

Function Get_Octet_IPAdd(octet_num As Usage_Get_Octet_IPAdd)

Dim octet As Integer

If octet_num = Octet_Num.first_octet Then
  Octet = 0
End If

If octet_num = Octet_Num.second_octet Then
  Octet = 1
End If

If octet_num = Octet_Num.third_octet Then
  Octet = 2
End If

If octet_num = Octet_Num.fourth_octet Then
  Octet = 3
End If

Dim fourthOctet As String = Format(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.130").GetAddressBytes(3), "000")
    Return fourthOctet
End Function
```

Comment: Enums is exactly for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

Enums is integer type and can be used as index in `.GetAddressBytes(index)`

```
Public Enum OctetNum
   First = 0
   Second = 1
   Third = 2
   Fourth = 3
End Enum

Function Get_Octet_IPAdd(octet_num As OctetNum)

    Return Format(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.130").GetAddressBytes(octet_num), "000")

End Function
```